# В drupal подправить h1

Tags: drupal, html

Есть страничка сайта
http://www.dc-lm.com/rental-cars/mercedes-benz-e-class-2014
если посмотреть на html код то можно будет увидеть строение h1 оно выглядет так

```
 <h1><a href="./Mercedes-Benz E class rental" class="active">Mercedes-Benz E class rental</a></h1>
```

а мне нужно вот так

```
 <a href="./Mercedes-Benz E class rental" class="active"><h1>Mercedes-Benz E class rental</h1></a>
```

при этом в файле sites/all/theme/cobra/page.tpl.php есть только такая строка

```
<h1 class="page-header"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
```

не подскажете хотя бы в каком направлении искать?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть где формируется переменная $title, она там оборачивается в l($text, $path, $options = array()) и либо там сразу подставлять h1, либо оборачивать в ссылку в шаблоне.